# 'Foreach Recipient in Recipients' not work correctly in Powershell

Tags: microsoft-outlook, powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-6.0

The recipients of a mail in Outlook 2010 are as follow.

[image: Screenshot]

I tried to use foreach to delete all of the existing recipients but it failed to delete all(but deleted some). Also the dummy Write-Host (the code below) worked in similar way.

But if test it only with dummy Write-Host, it outputs correctly as the number of recipients.

See below:

```
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\carrot\Desktop\Quotation\AutoSendTender>> foreach ($objRecipient in $objMailItem.Recipients){Write-Host $objRecipient.Name}
aaaa@yandex.com
cccc@yandex.com
bbbb@yandex.com
dddd@yandex.com

[DBG]: PS C:\Users\carrot\Desktop\Quotation\AutoSendTender>> foreach ($objRecipient in $objMailItem.Recipients){Write-Host $objRecipient.Name;$objRecipient.Delete()}
aaaa@yandex.com
bbbb@yandex.com
```

Why and how to fix?
Thanks.

Version: Powershell 5 on Windows 10

Comment: Hi. I don't have Outlook, so can't test with the actual object. But since no one has jumped in, here's how I'd start testing. What does `$objMailItem.Recipients.Count` return?  See if there's any obvious difference in the various recipients: `$objMailItem.Recipients.ForEach({ $_ | select * | out-gridview })`

Comment: You may go to Outlook for developer forum for more information.

Comment: maybe it is because the "$objMailItem.Recipients" is changed inside the foreach statement through the .Delete(). What if you first store the $objMailItem.Recipients in a temp variable and running your foreach in this variable ?